# Grab fixtures inside protected dataProvider method

Tags: php, codeception

I use [dataProvider protected methods](https://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage.html#DataProvider-Annotations) inside my Codeception Cest class.
It is possible to get fixtures inside dataProvider method? For example:

```php
class PageCest
{
   /**
    * @dataProvider pageProvider
    */
    public function staticPages(AcceptanceTester $I, \Codeception\Example $example)
    {
        $I->amOnPage($example['url']);
        $I->see($example['title'], 'h1');
        $I->seeInTitle($example['title']);
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    protected function pageProvider(): array
    {

        // Here I want to use some like $I->grabFixture()

        return [
            ['url'=>"/", 'title'=>"Welcome"],
            ['url'=>"/info", 'title'=>"Info"],
            ['url'=>"/about", 'title'=>"About Us"],
            ['url'=>"/contact", 'title'=>"Contact Us"]
        ];
    }
}
```